# PHP form action script not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

Script1 is based on CSS and html design(with some texture effect) I tried to setup php form action script to a html/css form however it keeps refreshing to the home page.. according to script if successful then it will refresh to thankyou.php, but it is not success.

However script2, I don't use any css, it is very basic html but it is working fine! but since my whole website design have css effect, I want the form also needs to have some css work.

Could someone please help me with script1? if it not possible then could you please suggest me an action script for below form, currently I don't have any action.php script, I tried few in online, unfortunately without success.

**CSS form script:**

```
<div class="row add-bottom-main">
    <form name="myform" id="contactForm" action="" method="post">  

        <article class="span6">
            <textarea  id="msg" rows="3" cols="40" name="message" placeholder="Message">Message</textarea>
        </article>

        <article class="span6">
            <input size="100" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
            <input type="text"  size="30" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-renova-alt add-top-half">Send Message</button>
        </article>

    </form>
</div>
```

**Script 1**

```
<div class="row add-bottom-main">
<?php 
$action=$_REQUEST['action']; 
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */ 
{ 
?> 
    <form name="myform" id="contactForm" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">  

        <article class="span6">
            <textarea  id="msg" rows="3" cols="40" name="message" placeholder="Message">Message</textarea>
        </article>

        <article class="span6">
            <input size="100" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
            <input type="text"  size="30" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-renova-alt add-top-half">Send Message</button>
        </article>

    </form>
<?php 
}  
else                /* send the submitted data */ 
{ 
    $name=$_REQUEST['name']; 
    $email=$_REQUEST['email']; 
    $message=$_REQUEST['message']; 
    if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message=="")) 
    { 
        echo "All fields are required, please fill again."; 
    }
    else
    {         
        $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 
        $subject="Message sent using your contact form"; 
        mail("niranjan.thampu@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $from); 
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=thankyou.php">';    
        exit;
    } 
}   
?>                         
</div>
```

**SCRIPT 2**

```
<div class="row add-bottom-main">
<?php 
$action=$_REQUEST['action']; 
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */ 
{ 
?> 
    <form name="myform" id="contactForm" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit"> 
    Your name:<br> 
    <input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 
    Your email:<br> 
    <input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 
    Your message:<br> 
    <textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br> 
    <input type="submit" value="Send email"/> 
    </form> 
<?php 
}  
else                /* send the submitted data */ 
{ 
    $name=$_REQUEST['name']; 
    $email=$_REQUEST['email']; 
    $message=$_REQUEST['message']; 
    if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message=="")) 
    { 
        echo "All fields are required, please fill again."; 
    } 
    else
    {         
        $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 
        $subject="Message sent using your contact form"; 
        mail("niranjan.thampu@capital-placement.com", $subject, $message, $from); 
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=thankyou.php">';    
        exit;
    } 
}   
?>                    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "css form" as posted has no action set on the form and no PHP to process the page in the event that it's submitted.  Your two other forms both have PHP that is testing to see if the form has been submitted and process it when it has.  The PHP on those two pages is doing the work of processing the form.  Without it, they would also not do anything when submit.